# Moving to the recommended svn strucure

Tags: svn, convention

I just started in this new company where the major project is checked in at the root of an svn repository with no branch or tag. I'd like to apply the svn convention of having a trunk,branch,tag structure. Can I just create those three directories and then just move everything under trunk? Will that preserve the history of every file?

So now it looks like this now:

```
svnRoot/
    projectFiles
```

and I would like something like

```
svnRoot/
    trunk/
        projectFiles
    branch/
    tag/
```

or even better

```
svnRoot/
    projet1/
        trunk/
            project1Files
        branch/
        tags/
    project2/
        trunk/
            project2Files
        branch/
        tags/
```

I understand that svn has no knowledge of trunk,branch and tag (they are just conventions) so since I'm just moving files around, I would expect svn to be able to keep the history of each file. I would just like confirmation of that.

Thanks

w.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible to proceed this way.

However, if you are using externals from outside or internally you need to update them as well. also there is a minor risk that frozen externals (without peg revision) will not resolve anymore.

You should also read and understand the section in SVN book about PEG vs. operational revisions.
http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.pegrevs.html

In short:

it is a different if you refer to /a/b/c.txt@100 or /a/b/c.txt -r 100. while the first one goes to revision 100 and looks up the file, the second one looks up the file and then follows the history down to rev. 100.

Comment: Thanks spiderman ;-). I'd never heard of pegs. I've learned something new today :-)